# FTP clients: why don't they start downloading right away?

Tags: ftp

A minute ago I wanted to download a Wordpress installation on one of my servers. This is an existing installation that I wanted to remove and download for backup. I fired up Cyberduck, my FTP-client, and dragged the folder into the Finder on my Mac. Then it took a really long time for Cyberduck to create an index of all files and folders before the actual download begins. To me this seems like a waste of time. Why doesn't the download start right away, when the first folder is indexed?

Comment: Progress reporting is very inaccurate without knowing the full list of files to transfer. That is one possible rationale.

Comment: Well, sometimes I think that this results in double the download time, and many times I don't care about a progress report. This is similar to Windows Explorer, copying a folder with thousands of files, which can take many minutes before it even starts.

Comment: It depends, of course. If you have many small files, the overhead will be very high. On the other hand, if you have very large files, it'll hardly matter at all.

Comment: This isn't a limitation of FTP so much as a limitation of the FTP client you are using. Filezilla, for example, doesn't wait.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general reasons for this could be two fold:

1)its to provide an ETA for completion.  Some FTP clients will enumerate everything before copying (like windows explorer does for lcoal copying).  This gives a starting file count and data size total - allowing creation of a guestimated ETA.

2)some poorer written FTP programs out there make a separate conenction to enumerate files while another connection does the download.  This uses one of the connections to the FTP box (which if you are only allowed 1 will leave you stumped)

3)there are a lot of overheads with jumping form a folder to enumerae, to a folder for download, then back and forth.. it can actually be faster to complete one job then another - again this is dependant on the coding and efficiency of the client.

Hope this helps.